# Average number of collected coupons problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, coupon-collector

I have the following problem.

> There are two kinds of coupons, $A$ and $B$. Each type has the same probability to be present in a box of cookies. You want to collect a complete set of coupons where there is at least one coupon for each type. What is the average number of boxes of cookies you need to buy?

I parametrize the number of boxes as $n=k_A + k_B$ where $k_{A,B}$ denotes the number of coupons of type $A$ or $B$ that one collects after they bought $n$ boxes. The probability of picking coupon A or B is the same, that is $p=1/2$.

I was thinking to solve this problem in the following way, but since I find a divergence I think my approach is not correct. I want to treat this problem in terms of a multinomial distribution of success variables $k_1$ and $k_2$.
The probability mass function would be
$$
\rho(k_1,k_2) = \frac{(k_1+k_2)!}{k_1! k_2!}p^{k_1+k_2}
$$

from which I can compute the expected value of $k_1 +k_2$ as

$$
\langle k_1 + k_2 \rangle = \frac{\sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty} \rho(k_1,k_2) (k_1+k_2)}{\sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty} \rho(k_1,k_2)} = \frac{2p}{1-2p}
$$

which diverges as I choose $p=1/2$. Of course, this cannot be correct. Where is the problem?

Comment: Going back to the question, does each box have exactly one coupon in the $p=\frac12$ case?  If so, you will have either $k_1=1$ or $k_2=1$ and the other at least as much.  So $\sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty}$ is not what you want

Comment: @Henry each box has exactly one coupon. If I buy 1 box, I can have $k_1=1$ or $k_2=1$. If I buy two boxes, I can have $(k_1,k_2) = (2,0),(1,1),(0,2)$ and so on. I don't understand why the sum is not correct. Can you expand your comment, please?

Comment: You stop when you have at least one of each type.  So you stop when you get the first coupon of the type you did not already have.  So at the end you have one coupon of one type and one or more of the other.  Your sums should be $\dfrac{ \sum_{k_1=1}^{\infty}(k_1+1)2^{-(k_1+1)}+ \sum_{k_2=1}^{\infty}(1+k_2)2^{-(1+k_2) }} {\sum_{k_1=1}^{\infty}2^{-(k_1+1)}+ \sum_{k_2=1}^{\infty}2^{-(1+k_2)}}$ though the denominator is $1$

Comment: @Henry thank you. Can I ask you the last thing? Can you express the denominator in terms of my function $\rho(k_1,k_2)$?

Comment: No - because your $\rho$ assumes any order, but the rules require a particular order, with the second type coming last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the expression that diverges is not an expected value. The probability $\rho(k_1,k_2)$ that you wrote down is the probability to draw $k_1$ and $k_2$ coupons of types $A$ and $B$, respectively, *given* that $k_1+k_2$ boxes are bought. So to get an expected value, you’d have to sum this over all values of $k_1$ and $k_2$ with that sum, not over all values in general; it’s not surprising that you get a diverging result if you do that. In any case, this expression has nothing to do with the expected value the question asks for, which is the expected value of boxes bought *until you have one of each type of coupon*. That latter condition doesn’t appear anywhere in your calcuation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that the condition "until you have one of each type of coupon" is not imposed - that's because I misunderstood the problem. Regarding the first part of your answer, is it correct or not that $\rho(k_1,k_2)$ is the probability to get $k_1$ coupons of type A and  $k_2$ coupons of type B for a given $n=k_1+k_2$? Why I cannot consider $\rho(k_1,k_2)$ as the probability mass function for $k_1$ and $k_2$?

Comment: @apt45: Yes, it's correct that $\rho(k_1,k_2))$ is the probability to get $k_1$ coupons of type $A$ and and $k_2$ coupons of type $B$ for a given $n=k_1+k_2$, and that's precisely why you can't use it as the probability mass function for $k_1$ and $k_2$ – because it's for given $n$. A probability mass function is normalized, i.e. it sums to $1$ over all events. Here you're using all probabilities for all $n$ at once, and since the ones for given $n$ already sum to $1$, all together they sum to infinity.

Comment: There's no probability mass function for all $k_1$ and $k_2$; that doesn't correspond to any experiment. There's a probability mass function for all $k_1$ and $k_2$ if you impose the condition that you stop once you have one of each type of coupon; but that is then a completely different problem that has little to do with $\rho(k_1,k_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume, without loss of generality, that the first box has coupon A.  So the question reduces to how many (more) boxes do you expect to need before finding a coupon B?

Let $E$ denote the expected number of additional boxes needed, after box 1, which is assumed to contain coupon A.

Then

$$E = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}(E + 1) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}E   \implies E = 2. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the LHS is explained by considering that $(1/2)$ the time, you will have found coupon B in the second box, and (1/2) the time, your situation will be just as it was, except that you have purchased one extra box.

Therefore, you should expect to need to buy $(E + 1) = 3$ boxes.

**Edit**
See also the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).  Also, you will find many similarly named mathSE questions posed.

Therefore, this entire question/answer may well be deleted as a duplicate.  Until it does, note that the method used in this answer will generalize to other types of Probability Sequence problems besides the Coupon Collector's Problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I didn't need another way to solve this problem, but I wanted to understand why my derivation is wrong. If you can find a question discussing solving this problem with this approach, I might agree that my question can be deleted.

Comment: I upvoted your answer btw

Comment: @apt45 Very good point.  I will leave that to the already posted comment of Henry.  I suspect that it will be very difficult to find a question where an approach similar to yours was taken, because it is much more complicated than is necessary.

Comment: I agree it is much more complicated, but I like to solve problems in several different ways to learn as much as possible. I am not interested in the particular solution, but if one way of solving the problem turns out to be not correct, this means that I am missing something that I should not have missed.

Comment: @apt45 You raise another **very** good (but somewhat subtle) point.  Your question is in danger of being closed as a duplicate, because similar questions have been asked many times before.  I recommend that you edit your question to emphasize the point that you have made in your comments to me.  This way, other MathSE reviewers will be (at least somewhat) reluctant to brand the question as a duplicate without providing a link that you **personally** consider to be on point.